# how automatically perform touch in android programmatically

Tags: android

I have a `RelativeLayout` I want to perform a touch event with out touching the screen want to give a `Toast` message if its actually touched or not.Please throw I have tried with the below it seems not working

```
MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, 
                                       x, y, pressure, size, 
                                       metaState, xPrecision, yPrecision, 
                                       deviceId, edgeFlags);
onTouchEvent(event);
```

Comment: How can you perform touch event without touching a screen!!!? It's like eating food without opening mouth.

Comment: Have you ever used tools like robotium ???

Comment: @Apurva  See in the accepted answer how developers do without touching..

Comment: Yeah sure, I got it  now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not do that. If you indeed want to "touch" your view programatically, you should wrap whatever happens in your onTouch method in another function(without the MotionEvent parameter) and call that function, when you want to touch your view. Calling the onTouch without a real touch would get you negative stylepoints

```
@Override
boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
  return action(me.getX(),me.getY());
}

boolean action(int x, int y) {
  //do some stuff
}

void somewhereelse() {
  //Perform touch action
  action(0,0);
}
```

If you really want to 'dispatch' a touch event. You do it like this:

```
View v;
v.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0,0,MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 100,100,0.5f,5,0,1,1,0,0));
```

The values are pretty random. Only the deviceId=0 indicates that it is programatically dispatched Touch.

Comment: It won't. My whole point is, that the onTouch method should never be executed, if the screen is not touched.

Comment: you are right but my question is without touching the view..But what's your opinion is it possible?

Comment: After touch the view @Override
boolean onTouch(MotionEvent me) {
  return action(me.getX(),me.getY());
}
not calling

Comment: try changing `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` to `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to simulate a real touch this can be good for webviews since they will only react on ACTION_UP I strongly advise you not to try this on ads since they will find out.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 Button btnTouch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_touch);
            btnTouch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    x++;
                    y++;
                    perFromTouch(x,y);
                }
            });

     private void perFromTouch(float x, float y) {

            // Obtain MotionEvent object
            long initTime = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long eventTime = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;


            // List of meta states found here:     developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getMetaState()
            int metaState = 0;
            MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    initTime,
                    eventTime,
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                    x,
                    y,
                    metaState
            );
            motionEvent.setSource(inputSource);
            v.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Find your layout in activity

```
RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findviewbyid(R.id.relativelayout);

layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //do your work
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Comment: But where in this code it would automatically touch.My understanding is if i am touching the view then it would call onTouch() right???

Comment: yes if you touch the perticular view then it is called