# Android auto-click programming

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I want to click on the screen by location, X, Y In a programming way

I tried to use this method.

[how automatically perform touch in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498079/how-automatically-perform-touch-in-android-programmatically/28498553)

Comment: "I tried to use this method." What happened when you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to awnser without any context. Can you give some info about what you are exactly trying to do?
From what I understand there are two options:

**Option 1:** (The hard way)

If you really want to perform a click as soon as an element moves to a specific coordinate you have to check for the position of the view.

```
int[] cornerPoint1 = new int[2] {xCorner1, yCorner1};
int[] cornerPoint2 = new int[2] {xCorner2, yCorner2};
int[] viewPosition = new int[2];
myView.getLocationOnScreen(viewPosition);

if(viewPosition[0] > cornerPoint1[0] && viewPosition[0] < cornerPoint2[0] && viewPosition[1] > cornerPoint1[1] && viewPosition[1] < cornerPoint2[1]){
  myView.PerformClick();
}
```

You should put this in a loop and it will check if a specific view moves into the space between `cornerPoint1` and `cornerPoint2`.
However i would not recommend that. Usually you want your code to be eventbased. This solution is against the general workflow of Android Studio.

**Option 2:** (Recommended)

From your questions it doesnt actually seem like you need a click. What you are trying to achieve would be better solved with your backend. The frontend is usally only used to give the user the option to tell the backend what to do.
So if you are trying to do something when a specific condition is met you dont need to simulate frontend-actions.

I cant tell you how exactly you should implement that, as I dont know what your project is.

Comment: I want to click on a specific location on the Fixed Location screen. I want to run the service on a dialer app
Of course using my app

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible to click outside of your app. If you want to dial a number from your app look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230912/android-app-to-call-a-number-on-button-click

Comment: Explain my intention more

Comment: Yes please do that. I cant help you if you cant give me detailed information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I snapped a picture that explains thank you very much
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1krjvMp_33NfmiqOYdVMs02C5V4Zn9dEK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That picture is from your internal phone app if im not mistaken. There is no way for you to automatically click on that button. There is an option however to automatically switch to your phone app from your own app and enter a phone number. The post I linked above shows how to do that.